# A quantity associated to a field extension

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, fields, field-extensions

Let $F\subset E$ be a field extension. So $E$ has a natural structure of $F$-vector space.
A vector subspace $V\subset E$ is a *special subspace* if $F\subset V$ and $V$ is closed under the inverse operator $i \colon E\to E$ with $i(a)=a^{-1}$.

> **Question.** For what kind of field extensions $F\subset E$ do we have but finitely many special subspaces? Is there a well-known
> interpretation for the number of such special subspaces when $E$ is a
> finite field?

Comment: Have you computed the number for any pairs of finite fields?

Comment: This quantity is finite (in fact $2$) for a quadratic extension at least when $p \ne 2$, since, in that case, if $x \in V \setminus F$, then $x$ and $\overline x = \operatorname N_{E/F}(x)x^{-1}$ lie in $V$ and together span $E$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure quadratic extensions with $V = F \sqrt{\alpha}$ are the only such subfields; it's not hard to show that if $a, b \in V$, then $\frac{a^2}{b} \in V$, with small restrictions to prevent division by $0$. Using that, you can show that $\frac{ab}{c} \in V$ (under similar restrictions), so you get an underlying field $F'$ such that $V$ is one-dimensional over $F$, and the rest should be simple.

Comment: I should note that my answer below works in all cases of characteristic not equal to 2, but leaves characteristic 2 open. The proof of the first statement ($\frac{a^2}{b} \in V$) is still valid, but the second ($\frac{ab}{c} \in V$) is not, and I suspect that for $E$ infinite there will be some cases where it is not true.

Comment: @user44191's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/391442) below, referenced in their [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391432/a-quantity-associated-to-a-field-extension#comment998450_391432).

Comment: There's been some recent [work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869319303722)  by Edison and Iovanov where they look at what are called "invertible-2" algebras. These are algebras which have a basis $\mathcal B$ which is closed under the inversion operator. You might find something of interest there, especially Proposition 3.5, where they show that any algebraic extension of a field $E$ is Invertible-2

Comment: @dbossaller, do you have a precise [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391432/a-quantity-associated-to-a-field-extension#comment998490_391432)?  It's not obvious on [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=Edison+and+Iovanov).

Comment: Link: [On Invertible Algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869319303722)

Comment: @dbossaller thank you for the link and your attention to my question.

Comment: @LSpice  Thank you for your comment, your edit and your attention to my question.

Answer (score 4):

For the rest of this post, I'm talking about fields not of characteristic $2$. Under this assumption, we will show that any such $V$ is either a subfield of $E$ or is a complement of a subfield $F'$ inside a quadratic extension $F' \oplus V$ of $F'$ of the form $F' \sqrt{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in F'$.

We first prove that if $a, b \in V$ with $b\neq 0$, then $\frac{a^2}{b} \in V$. I will list expressions that must also be elements of $V$:

$\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{a + b}{ab}, \frac{ab}{a + b}, \frac{ab}{a + b} - a = -\frac{a^2}{a + b}, \frac{a + b}{a^2}, \frac{a + b}{a^2} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{b}{a^2}, \frac{a^2}{b}$

(Here we only run into problems with inversion at $0$ if one of $a$, $b$, or $a + b$ is zero; if $a=0$ then $\frac{a^2}{b}=0 \in V$, while if $a+b=0$ then $\frac{a^2}{b}= \frac{b^2}{b} =b\in V$, so the claim is valid even in these cases.)

We next prove that if $a, b, c \in V$ with $c\neq 0$, then $\frac{ab}{c} \in V$. Again, I will list expressions that must be elements of $V$:

$\frac{(a + b)^2}{c}, \frac{a^2 + b^2}{c}, \frac{2ab}{c}, \frac{ab}{c}$.

Fix some $c\in V$ nonzero. Let $F'$ be the set of elements of $E$ of the form $\frac{b}{c}$ for $b\in V$. Then I claim that $F'$ is closed under addition, multiplication, and inversion, and so is a field. Addition is automatic, multiplication follows from $\frac{a}{c} \frac{b}{c} = \left(\frac{ab}{c} \right)/c$, and inversion follows from $\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{-1} = \left( \frac{c^2}{b} \right)/c$.

But then we have that $c^{2} = \left( \frac{c^2}{c^{-1}}\right)/c \in F'$, so $F' \oplus V = F'[c]$ is a quadratic extension of $F'$ (unless $V = F'$ itself). So what you're looking for really are pairs of subfields of $E$ where one is a quadratic extension of the other, or just subfields of $E$.

---

We now turn to the characteristic 2 case. For $E$ finite, the answer is still simple: $V$ must be a subfield of $E$.

Proof: First, I claim that if $V$ is nontrivial, then $1 \in V$.

Choose any nonzero $c \in V$, and choose some generator $\alpha \in E$. Let $n$ be the smallest nonzero exponent such that $c \alpha^n \in V$. Then we can use induction to show that $c \alpha^{xn} \in V$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, as $c \alpha^{(x + 1) n} = \frac{(c \alpha^{xn})^2}{c \alpha^{(x - 1)n}}$, and similar induction for negative exponents. In the other direction, we can see that if $d \in V$, then as $\alpha$ is a generator, we have that $d = c \alpha^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$; it's not hard to see that $n|m$ (as otherwise, $n$ wouldn't be the smallest), so we have that $V = \{c \alpha^{xn}\}_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \cup \{0\}$.

Note that $|E| - 1$ must be divisible by $n$ - and in particular, $n$ is odd. But then as $c^{-1} \in V$, we must have that $c^{-1} = c \alpha^{x n}$, so $c^{2} = \alpha^{(|E| - 1) - xn} = \alpha^{2(|E| - 1) - xn}$. One of the two exponents is even, and half of that is still divisible by $n$ - so we get that $c = \alpha^{x_0 n}$ for some $x_0$. But then $1 = \alpha^{|E| - 1} = c \alpha^{|E| - 1 - x_0 n} \in V$.

By applying the above argument, this time with $c = 1$, we get that $V = \alpha^{xn} \cup \{0\}$ - so it must be closed under multiplication. We already had that it was closed under inversion and addition, so it is a subfield of $E$.

The question is still open for $E$ infinite of characteristic 2.

Comment: I cannot follow the argument. First, since $V$ is a (nonzero) $F$-linear space, the set of elements of $F$ of the form $\frac bc$ for $b,c\in V$ is clearly just $F$ itself. Second, in the last paragraph, some $a$ springs into being suddenly; what is it? Can you just state clearly at the outset what you are trying to prove?

Comment: I fixed Emil Jeřábek's complaints and also dealt with the division by zero (which was as easy as you suspected). Feel free to revert any or all of it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek For your first part, I don't see why it would be $F$ itself unless you assume that $V$ is 1-dimensional. Consider $F = \mathbb{Q}, E = \mathbb{C}, V = \mathbb{R}i$. For the second, the $a$ itself isn't really important, except to just have *some* nonzero member of $V$ - the transition from $V$ to $F'$ is something like the transition from an affine space to its underlying vector space.

Comment: It was $F$ itself as you originally defined it. Since Will Sawin changed the $F$ in the definition to $E$, it is not $F$ any longer. I.e., it seems this was just a typo, but I couldn’t figure that out.

Comment: "Here we only divide by $a$ and $b$" should be "Here we only divide by $a$, $b$, and $a + b$", right?

Comment: @LSpice Edited (both to address your comment and for a bit of clarity), thank you for checking.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For $F$ of characteristic $2$, a space $V$ has this form if and only if there are fields $F_1, F_2$ with $F \subseteq F_1 \subseteq F_2 \subseteq E$ and $F_2^2 \subseteq F_1$, and $V$ is an $F_1$-linear subspace of $F_2$.

For "if", by definition $V$ is $F_1$-linear, thus $F$-linear, and if $0 \neq a \in V$ then $a \in F_2$ so $a^2 \in F_1$ and thus $a^{-1} =(a^2)^{-1} a  \in V$ by $F_1$-linearity.

For "only if", by user44191's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/391442), if $a, b\in V$ then $a^2 b^{-1} \in V$. Because $V$ is closed under inverses, we get $a^2 b \in V$. Let $F_1$ be the field generated by squares of elements of $V$, then this identity shows $V$ is stable under multiplication by elements of $F_1$. Let $F_2$ be the field generated by $V$. We have $F_1 \subseteq F_2$ and $V$ is an $F_1$-linear subspace of $F_2$. Finally, because squaring is a field homomorphism in characteristic $2$ and $V^2 \subseteq F_1$ by definition, $F_2^2 \subseteq F_1$.

Thus, in characteristic $2$, there are finitely many such if and only if $E/F$ is finite separable — otherwise we can find a nontrivial pair $F_1$, $F_2$ and then there will be infinitely many one-dimensional $F_1$-linear subspaces of $F_2$ (we can assume $F_1$ is infinite because finite fields have no inseparable extensions).

Comment: thank you and +1 for your answer.

Comment: This also works as a cleaner solution for the finite case, as it gives the answer (that $V = F_2$) quite easily: $F_2$ is a finite field of characteristic 2, so $F_2 \supseteq V \supseteq F_2^2 = F_2$.